# PayerPrefs Unity C# не сохраняет данные

Tags: c#, unity3d

Уже битый час ломаю голову, пытаюсь сохранить простейшие данные (код прикреплю ниже).

 Ничего не работает, не подгружает данные при старте приложения и не сохраняет, как видно на выходе.

```
public class ClickButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    // buttons
    private Button btnClick;

    // labels
    private Text textScore;

    // data of player
    public int count_clicks;
    public int money;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MONEY");
        textScore = GameObject.Find("lblScoreText").GetComponent<Text>();
        textScore = money.ToString();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        textScore.text = money.ToString();
    }

    public void OnClickTheButton()
    {
        this.count_clicks++;
        this.money++;

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MONEY", money);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

}
```

Comment: PlayerPrefs.Save(); подпишите после того как сохраняете SetInt

Comment: @walkinrey, благодарю

Comment: @walkinrey, попробовал... Does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

```
public class ClickButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    // buttons
    private Button btnClick;

    // labels
    private Text textScore;

    // data of player
    public int count_clicks;
    public int money;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MONEY");
        textScore = GameObject.Find("lblScoreText").GetComponent<Text>();
        textScore = money.ToString();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        textScore.text = money.ToString();
    }

    public void OnClickTheButton()
    {
        this.count_clicks++;
        this.money++;

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MONEY", money);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

}
```